# Strange signs after "

Tags: input-encodings

i get some strange effects after a " sign in my latex document.

Here is my \usepackage section:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{titlepage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,linktoc=none]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{listings}
```

And here are a few section where the strange things apere:

Source:
`Paketmanagers "apt-get" der`

Render:
`Paketmanagersäpt-get"der`

Source:
`"hostapd", "iw" und "dnsmasq" benötigt`

Render:
`"hostapd", ïwünd "dnsmasq"benötigt`

Can someone help me to fix them? This is my first work in latex

Phill93

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should never use `"` for quotes; with `ngerman` for `babel` it's even worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also using German quotes in LaTeX, but i take the [csquotes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes?lang=de) package. I can quote a word by using

```
\enquote{Test1}
```

I'm using TeXstudio as IDE, it has an option in "Editor" -> "Replace quotes" where you can select the csqoutes package. Texstudio automatically replaces the first `"` with `\enqoute{`, the second `"` with `}`. This is very nice, you can type like in a standard editor or office software.

Answer (score 6):

You should **never** use `"` as quotation mark in LaTeX. Proper ones are `''` (please observe two characters) for closing ones and language dependent version for opening ones (I do not know German typographic rules).

Comment: `\glqq\grqq` produce nice german quotation marks.

Answer (score 4):

`babel` makes the catcode of `"` active, so this character acts as a command itself, and not as an ordinary quote. You can look into the `babel` [documentation](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/german/ngermanb.pdf) and find quite a few additional commands like `"a`, `"s`, `"<` etc.